# dropbox integration iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, dropbox

I am Beginner in iPhone. I wants Integrate Dropbox Api in my App for upload a .pdf file and image. But after long googling in not find any good tutorial for it.

Please provide me any tutorial links. or any example link where i can get information about how to integrate dropbox and upload file.

Many Thanks

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685442/iphone-dropbox-api-how-to-load-a-file) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811932/data-syncing-with-dropbox-api-and-ios).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Requirements:**

1. You need the 4.0 version of the iPhone SDK. The version of your XCode should
   be at least 3.2.3.
2. You need to have registered as a Dropbox application with [mobile access](http://dropbox.com/developers). You should have a consumer key and secret.
3. You need to download the [dropbox sdk](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/releases)

Refer to [this](http://programmaticallytakingscreenshot.blogspot.in/2011/04/dropbox-integration-in-iphone.html) link for more details and example.